# toContainReact function is not recognized while testing react component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to use `https://github.com/FormidableLabs/enzyme-matchers/blob/master/packages/jest-enzyme/README.md#tocontainreact`

**// App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// ...

import Pagination from "./components/Pagination";
// ...

export default class App extends Component {
  //  ...
  render() {
    return (
      // ...
      <Pagination />
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting error for following test.

**// App.test.js**

```
import {mount} from 'enzyme';

import App from "../App";
import Pagination from "../components/Pagination";

it('renders component', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<App />); 
  expect(wrapper.toContainReact(<Pagination/>)); // error
});
```

Error:

> TypeError: wrapper.toContainReact is not a function

If I remove assertion, test is passed.

```
it('renders component', () => {
   const wrapper = mount(<App />); 
}); // test is passed, so I'm assuming no installation or configuration issues
```

so, why toContainReact() is not recognized?

**Edit:**

`expect(wrapper.toContain(<Pagination/>));` // this also didnot work

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
    ...
  },
```

Comment: What version of enzyme are you using? It seems that `toContainReact` was previously named `toContain` in [this change log](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/enzyme-matchers/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100)

Comment: package.json

`"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
...  },`

 "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2", ... seems to be latest